# Magento 2 Composer error when trying to install modules [UnexpectedValueException]

Tags: magento2, composer

I'm trying to install a module with magento 2 composer. However, when I try the command:

```
composer require sendcloud/sendcloud
```

**I see an error:**

```
[UnexpectedValueException]
RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(vendor/magmodules/packages): failed to open dir: No such file or directory
```

**Earlier, I tried to install a module :**

```
composer config repositories.magmodulesartifacts artifact vendor/magmodules/packages
composer require magmodules/GoogleShopping:1.1.4
```

But. that wasn't very successful. Probably, it's related with that. Then, I installed that module via FTP.

Please help me fix this error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't have `magmodules/packages` module in vendor folder. Please make sure you have already installed `magmodules/packages` module.

If not installed then first installed that module.
https://www.magmodules.eu/help/googleshopping-magento2

Comment: Thanks.

I have installed and transfered the zip of the magmodule to /var/magmodules/packages as the installation on that website asks for that.

Comment: How you installed `magmodules/packages` module? By composer or manually?

Comment: the google shopping module i've installed manually i think.

Comment: Please use this link to installed that nodule.
https://www.magmodules.eu/help/googleshopping-magento2/install-magento2-extension-composer

Comment: Yes, i did that already.

Comment: If you use same then it should create `magmodules/packages` folder under vendor folder.

Comment: When i use     composer require magmodules/GoogleShopping:1.1.4, after omposer config repositories.magmodulesartifacts artifact vendor/magmodules/packages command it shows same error as above. Unexpectedvalueexception