# Composer update fail: [UnexpectedValueException]

Tags: composer, third-party-module, magento2.4.0

[Magento 2 Composer error when trying to install modules [UnexpectedValueException]](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/299349/70292)
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/316793/70292

During composer update command UnexpectedValueException was occur.
https://prnt.sc/vd2ava

```
 [UnexpectedValueException]
  RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(MageworxModule/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory
```

I have tried the above solutions but not works.
I have added 777 permission to app/ pub/ generated/ var/
I have also checked and found that in app/code/MageworxModule module was already available.

Answer (score 1):

I found that in the Magento root directory composer.json this repository.

```
repository:{
     "mageworx": {
            "type": "artifact",
            "url": "MageworxModule/"
     },
}
```

So I have added folder MageworxModule folder in Magento root and add extension zip inside it and the error was resolved.
[image: composer update successfully]
Thank you.